# Scrolling UIImageViews getting "Low Memory Warning"

Tags: memory-leaks, uiscrollview, uiimageview, uiimage

My application is relatively simple - basically a `UIScrollView` to look at a couple of hundred (large) JPEGs. Yet it is crashing consistently with a "Low Memory Warning"

The scroll view consists of three `UIImageView`s (`previousPage`, `currentPage`, and `nextPage`). Upon starting, and every time the current page is scrolled, I "reset" the three `UIImageView`s with new `UIImages`.

```
NSString *previousPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:previousName ofType:@"jpg"];
previousPage.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:previousPath];
currentPage.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:currentPath];
nextPage.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:nextPath];
```

Running in Allocations, the number of `UIImage` objects #living stays constant through the running of the app, but the number of #transitory `UIImage` objects can grow quite high.

Is this a problem? Is there some way that I can be 'releasing' the `UIImage` objects? Am I right in thinking this is the source of what must be a memory leak?

Comment: Looks right to me. You could try to explicitly set the image property to nil before attaching new images to them. previousPage.image = nil; previousPage.image = [UIImage imageWith...]

Comment: That didn't help, but thanks joern. (I like your blog!) Is it possible the jpegs themselves are too large for my iPad2 to handle in any quantity? They range up to 10MB, and as large as 4000x3000+ pixels.

Comment: That might be a factor. Have you had a look of your app's memory usage using Instruments?

Comment: Memory usage is all over the map. I can easily get up to 300 MB "Physical Memory Used", and easily down to a few MB "Physical Memory Free". And multiple "Low Memory Warning" - which will quickly, or later, crash the app on the iPad2. -- I guess the next test I should try, is much smaller images (both in pixel dimensions, and quality of jpeg)

Comment: If it works paging through for a little while, but then crashes with a memory error, it's not fundamentally related to image size (although those are quite large images).  If it can load three of the images, this technique should allow for a steady usage of memory (assuming resolution aside, the images are basically the same size).  Note, you are needlessly re-loading the same large image files more than once as you page through - a better design would only have these images get loaded once.